# What is the PCB name of this speaker connector?

Tags: pcb-design, connector, eaglecad, terminal

I am designing a PCB board in EasyEDA for a DIY audio amp. I have searched in several places to find the proper technical name of this speaker connector but I could not find it.

I searched in Mouser and LCSC with the following keywords (speaker clip, spring clip, speaker connector, speaker terminal, binding post, spade connector) but I could not find anything related to this picture.

[image: spring speaker connector]

I want to find a proper component for EasyEDA or Eagle so that I know the correct dimensions on the PCB.

However on Amazon or AliExpress I can find by typing speaker spring connector.

Does anyone knows the correct name so that I can find a component and use it?

This is Amazon [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00H8VDRY0) in case someone needs it.

Comment: Typically you have to make your own footprint with a data sheet and or calipers.  Typically you *should* even if you find one made to someone else's preferences and beliefs.

Comment: Buy one, then measure it yourself.  Otherwise, a frequent comment here is "no datasheet, no sale!"

Comment: While not exactly the same thing, [this](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/phoenix-contact/1985195/277-1622-ND/568659) is the same type of connector and the link may be of use.

Comment: How about [this one](https://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/gc-electronics/2870).

Comment: @PeterBennett I have one at my disposal, but I don't have accurate measurement tools. I will use the datasheet drawing that was linked by brhans. Thanks

Comment: Or, measure the pin pitch and misuse any footprint that has 4 pins in line in that pitch.... or 8 pins of half that pitch etc ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called terminal blocks with quick connects, or connector barier strip blocks or speaker terminal blocks.

Search for this on digikey: CONN BARRIER SPKR STRIP

Comment: Thanks for pointing out digikey site. I found a corresponding [datasheet drawing](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/GC%20Electronics%20PDFs/33-1404_Dwg.pdf) that I can use to extract exact measurements.